# How to run python scripts in Atom if F5 is not working?

Tags: python, windows-runtime, atom-editor

I want to run my Python code within ATOM  in Win10

I have installed all packeges like: atom-python-run, script but anyway the program is not runnig.

In official page written to press F5 ,F6  to run script but doing that tries to compile the script with the gpp package (which I had installed before) as if it were C/C++ code.

Is it possible to change button for running a python script?

Comment: You can change Atom's default keybindings to do whatever you want. Here's a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5POoGSrtGg) showing how to get to the place in the program's Preferences where's that can be done.

Comment: I run my python codes in Atom by using the script extension.  Open Atom and then open the file you want to run. Go to the Program Menu and select script from that menu.  When Script opens just select run script,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to press additional fn key along with f5 or f6.